# Can't access SlideMasterPart in PowerPoint using OpenXml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I am trying to create a pptx file on the fly using [this OpenXml tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee412267.aspx).

I am getting the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

on the following line:

```
var slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.First();
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you missing this namspace  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging ?

Comment: No, I've got that one.  OpenXml, Packaging and Presentation.

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq;` or a reference to System.Xml.Linq

Comment: @AquilaSands That did it!  No idea how but adding a reference to System.Linq fixed it.  Any explanation?  Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the reference to `using System.Linq;`

By way of explanation, the `First()` method is an extension method that lives in the `System.Linq` namespace and is applied to anything that inherits from `IEnumerable`. See the MSDN docs [Enumerable.First Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [System.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the type name that will be returned:

```
var slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.First<**NameOfType**>();
```

Cheers -

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not recognise `First` at all.

Comment: The error implies that SlideMasterParts is a generic IEnumerable (i.e. IEnumerable<T> for some T). Generic IEnumerables do have a First<T> method. If it's not a generic IEnumerable, then what type is it?